# How to configure simple game AI setting with jtable

Tags: java

I'm developing an application that has methods of this kind:

```
attackIfIsFar();
protectIfIsNear();
helpAfterDeadOf();
helpBeforeAttackOf();
```

etc.

The initialization of my application for n players is something like

```
player1.attackIfIsFar(player2);
player2.protectIfIsNear(player4);
player3.helpAfterDeadOf(player1);
player4.helpBeforeAttackOf(player3);
```

etc.

I don't know how to configure a jtable that that can allow me to set the equivalent of this code-block

In others words I need simply a way to create a jtable with 3 column and n row, were I can set in the column 1 and 3, the player, and in the central column one of the available methods that each player on the column 1 must invoke on each player of column 3

Comment: Can you add more info?  Does player1 do all of those things to all other players?  The same with the other players?  Is it any combination of playerX - action - playerY?  Can Player1 to X and Y to Player 2?

Comment: what do the players is not important... I need simply a way to create a jtable with 3 column and n row were I can set in the column 1 and 3, the player, and in the central column the methods that each player on the column 1 must invoke on each player of column 3

Comment: Hmm... Having only seen what you've posted: this code is going to become a huge mess very fast, if it isn't already. If you haven't, do yourself a huge favour and take a look at the state pattern and goal-based agent behaviour(s).

Comment: I know the state pattern... why I should use the state pattern in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need an class to represent the expression.

```
public class Expression {
  private Person lhs;
  private Person rhs;
  private Action action;
}
```

Then you need to make a [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) that is backed by a list of `Expression`s. Column count will be 3 and row count will be the size of the list. The rest of the methods are fairly straight forward to implement by mapping the row and/or column to the respective `Expression` and/or field.

Then you need a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) that sets the `TableCellEditor` for each column. Each of which would be a combo box with the available options for the respective field. If you need more help with tables, read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Once all the values are configured, you will need to create some logic that will evaluate the expressions and calls the correct methods.

**Edit**
Here is a very basic cell editor example. You could take steps to not populate the combo boxes with a value that will allow the user to select an invalid value.

```
@Override
public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int col)
{
  switch (col) {
  case 0:
  case 2:
    return new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(LIST_OF_PEOPLE));
  case 1:
    return new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(LIST_OF_ACTIONS));
  default:
    return super.getCellEditor(row, col);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you give me more details about setting of TableCellEditor? thanks

Comment: I haven't understand, how to integrate the lists in cells of table.

Comment: @Asgard: I had a small issue, `DefaultCellEditor` takes a `JComboBox` not a list. As for the values in the cells, you need to make a list of `Expression`. Then row 0 maps to the item at index 0 in the list.

Comment: Could you give me more code? Where should I put the `@Override
public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int col){`? The class with my table extends JFrame. Thanks

Comment: @Asgard: You should make a new class that extends `JTable` that implements `getCellEditor()`, then use that class in your `JFrame`.